# Sorting arrays with the same order

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm making a program to make a list of people, with 3 different marks of time (in double)
To do it, I made 4 arrays, One String, to save people names, and 3 Doubles to save the 3 marks on the years 2010, 2011, and 2012.
In the menu, I have to implement an option to sort the list on 2012s mark, in descending order.

Like this

```
m12[0] = 12.1
m12[1] = 34.1
m12[2] = 23.1
m12[3] = 23.5
```

into:

```
m12[1] = 34.1
m12[3] = 23.5
m12[2] = 21.1
m12[0] = 12.1
```

I did it with a basic algorithm, but now I want to know if it's possible to get the actual order of the arrays, ([1],[3],[2],[0]) and apply it to the other arrays I have to print it as a list based on the 2012 mark in descending order.

Thats the code I have to make the normal order list:

```
            if(option==2){
            System.out.println("# , Name, 2010, 2011, 2012");
            for(i=0;i<dorsal.length-1;i++){
                if(dorsal[i]!=0){
                    System.out.println(dorsal[i]+"- "+nom[i]+", "+m10[i]+", "+m11[i]+", "+m12[i] );
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Press ENTER to return");
            intro.nextLine();
        }
```

Sorry if I didnt explained it very good, I started programming 3 months ago and I'm so newbie.

//EDIT
I'll paste here the head of the exercise:

Thats exactly the programs needs to do. I'm stucked at point 3.

The objective is to develop a program to manage a list of members of
in a competition of long jump. The number of places available is 15.
Their data will be introduced in the same order in which the athletes
enroll. Design a program that shows the following options:
1 – Register a participant
2 – List all the participant’s data
3 – List all the participant’s data by mark
4 – Quit
If 1 is selected, data of one of the participants will be introduced:
Name, best mark in 2012, best mark in 2011 and best mark in 2010.
If 2 is selected, we have to list all participant’s data ordered by dorsal
number (the order they’ve enrolled)
If 3 is selected, we have to list all participant’s data ordered by 2012
mark, from greater to smaller.
After processing each option, the main menu must be shown again,
till the option 4 is selected, quitting the program.

Thanks.

Comment: You should definitely replace your 4 arrays with 1 array containing custom `Person` objects.

Comment: how about using Arrays.sort(double[] array) and then accessing element s from back.

Comment: If you are going to do this using a plain array instead of OOP way: Then i can see `the dooms day is very near to us`. If you are going to say someone is forcing you to do this(As most of the OP responds after OOP suggestion is made) and you are complying with him then i can see: `the dooms day is even more nearer`

Answer (score 2):

Define a class to contain the data for each person, such as:

```
public class Person
{
    private String name;
    Private Map<Integer,Double> marks = new HashMap<Integer,Double>();
    public Person(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public void setMark(int year, double mark) {
        this.marks.put(year,mark); 
    }
    public void getMark(int year) {
        // return zero if there's no mark for the requested year
        return this.marks.containsKey(year) ? this.marks.get(year) : 0;
    }
}
```

Then write a `Comparator<Person>`

```
public PersonComparatorOnMarkDescending implements Comparator<Person>
{
    private int yearToCompare;
    public PersonComparator(int yearToCompare) {
        this.yearToCompare = yearToCompare;
    }
    public compare(Person p1, Person p2)
    {
        Integer p1Mark = p1.getMark(yearToCompare);
        Integer p2Mark = p2.getMark(yearToCompare);
        return p2.compareTo(p1);
    }
}
```

You can then define a `List<Person>` or a `Person[]` array and use the sorting methods available in `java.util`.  Instantiate the comparator with, for instance:

```
Comparator<Person> comp = new PersonComparatorOnMarkDescending(2012);
```

This approach lets you sort the collection on any year's marks.